# SunburstR: how to define paths i.e. add more layers to sunburst?

Tags: r, sunburst-diagram

I am lost in how to create the hierarchy with R's SunburstR package

```
sunburstR::sunburst(data=as.data.frame(iris, legendOrder=list("Species", "Sepal.Length")))
```

[image: n]

where the pedagocical example tries to create a hierarchy with the well-known iris dataset. The inner most layer would have 3 groups: setosa, versicolor and virginica -- and outmost layers showing the proportion of certain numeric things such as sepal length.

### **How to add more layers to a sunburst plot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the path with each node separated by dash such that

```
iris 
%>% mutate(path = paste(Species, Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, sep='-')) 
%>% select(path, Petal.Length) %>% sunburst()
```

where `Petal.Length` here is the value you want to visualise on the outermost layer with respect to the path starting from the innermost layer to the outermost layer

[image]

and in visually more pleasing order such that

[image]

```
iris 
%>% arrange(desc(Petal.Length), desc(Sepal.Length), desc(Petal.Width)) 
%>% mutate(path = paste(Species, Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, sep='-')) 
%>% select(path, Petal.Length) 
%>% sunburst(breadcrumb = list(w=200))
```